# SPARQL select labels with special characters

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have a question concerning SPARQL. I´m automaticially generating SPARQL queries in Javascript. I have a Dropdown Menu with strings that can be searched for. When generating the Query this works fine, as long as my "String" doesn't contain special characters:

```
select ?coin ?place where {
   ?coin nmo:hasObjectType nm:coin.
   ?coin nmo:hasFindspot ?findspotid. 
   ?findspotid rdfs:label ?place.
   FILTER regex(?place, "String", "i") .
} LIMIT 10
```

If I put something like "Köln" or "Chmielów", I don´t get a result even though there should be a lot. Instead the Query transforms the String to "KÃ¶ln" and "ChmielÃ³w". If I query this, I don´t get a result either.

Is there a way of automaticially escaping Special Characters? I don´t know the String before.

Comment: The problem appears to be using ISO-8859-1 encoded characters and putting them unconverted into UTF-8 SPARQL.  Presumably, the dropdown menu is working in ISO-8859-1 or other one-byte/one-char encoding. SPARQL is UTF-8.